# Remapping alt+shift, and waiting for an additional keypress

Tags: autohotkey, remapping

I'm trying to use AutoHotKey to remap <kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>left shift</kbd> according to the following conditions:

- If <kbd>left alt</kbd>+ <kbd>left shift</kbd> are pressed, wait for both to be released.
- Then, once both released:
  If the key <kbd>1</kbd> was pressed with them (i.e., <kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>left shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>), send 1.
  Else, if the key <kbd>2</kbd> was pressed with them (i.e., <kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>left shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>), send 2.
  Else, send 3.

However, I always get 3 sent.

What am I doing wrong?

```
LAlt & LShift::WaitAndSend()
WaitAndSend() {
  KeyWait, LAlt
  KeyWait, LShift
  if (GetKeyState(1)) {
    Send, 1
  } 
  else if (GetKeyState(2)) {
    Send, 2
  }
  else {
    Send, 3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [built-in variable](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#BuiltIn) [**A_PriorKey**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#h) is the  name of the
>   last key which was pressed prior to the most recent key-press or
>   key-release in the key history.

```
LAlt & LShift::WaitAndSend()

WaitAndSend() {
    KeyWait, LAlt
    KeyWait, LShift
    If (A_PriorKey = "1")
        Send, 1
    else If (A_PriorKey = "2")
        Send, 2
    else
        Send, 3
}
```

Comment: I'm going to check if it works, but can you please explain **(1)** why using `GetKeyState` doesn't result in the required outcome? **(2)** Also, I can't make sense of using `A_PriorKey` here: the key press order is `lalt`, then `lshift`, then `1` (or `2`), thus *the most recent key-press* is `1` (or `2`), and so `A_PriorKey` should return `lshift`. What do I miss?

Comment: `GetKeyState` works **only** for `left alt+left shift+1` and `left alt+left shift+2` if you add `KeyWait, 1, L` and `KeyWait, 2, L`. A_PriorKey is the last key pressed before LAlt and LShift are released.